# NSError with Parse.com code 100 not connecting to server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, nserror

The Parse.com support site says all systems are up. But all my apps queries are hanging and returning with NSError:

```
(NSError *) domain: @"Parse" - code: 100
```

This started randomly last night.  I have not hit my quota yet either.

What's up?

Thanks.